# Pandas merge is not working with identical keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the example from [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# Works
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                   'value1': [1, 2, 3, 5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'rkey': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                    'value2': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
```

And that works fine.

But if I try with a dataframe with identical keys:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                   'value1': [1, 2, 3, 5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo'],
                    'value2': [5, 6, 7, 8]})

df1.merge(df2, left_on='key', right_on='key')
```

I get this error:

```
    self._cache.clear()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clear'
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: FYI, I don't get that error with pandas 1.3.2.

Comment: I don't get this with Pandas 1.2.4 either.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if something is wrong with my Pycharm or virtual env...

Comment: What's `print(pd.__version__)`?

Comment: It is 1.3.2. But I just found that if I switch to Pycharm CE it doesn't occur, so something appears to be wrong with my Pycharm Professional installation.

Comment: It was because I had something wrong with my virtual environment -- deleting the virtual environment and starting over fixed it